# Button Screen Change in Android Mono using delegates

Tags: c#, android, visual-studio-2010, mono, xamarin.android

The following code is from the C# portion of my Android Mono application.  It is going to eventually be the GUI for a multimeter simulator, but right now just displays text.  It is rather straight forward:

-Click one of the buttons to go to that meter (voltmeter, ammeter, ohmmeter)
-Click the "re-scan" button and a TextView tells you how many times you clicked that button.
-Click one of the other meter buttons or the home button to switch views

That much is working flawlessly.  Unfortunately, once I switch views, the buttons cease to work.  Below is the code for the Ohm button and the Amp button.  The Ohm button is the 'complete' one that brings up views of all of the other screens.  For testing purposes, I was going to the amp screen but when I go there, its re-scan button does nothing.  None of the buttons do anything.

I am *fairly* certain that the issue is my use of the **delegate** commands, but none of my research has led me in any way towards a solution.

I can provide more of the main code and the XML code if needed.

```
ampButton.Click += delegate
            {
                SetContentView(Resource.Layout.AmpScreen);
                Button ampButtonData = FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.CurrentButtonamp);
                TextView ampData = FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.ampdata);
                ampButtonData.Click += delegate
                {
                    ampData.Text = string.Format("{0} clicks!", count2++);
                };
                Button amp2volt = FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.Amp2VoltButton);
                Button amp2ohm = FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.Amp2OhmButton);
                Button amp2home = FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.Amp2HomeButton);
            };


            ohmButton.Click += delegate
            {
                SetContentView(Resource.Layout.OhmScreen);
                Button ohmButtonData = FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.CurrentButtonohm);
                TextView ohmData = FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.ohmdata);
                ohmButtonData.Click += delegate
                {
                    ohmData.Text = string.Format("{0} clicks!", count3++);
                };

                Button ohm2amp = FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.Ohm2AmpButton);
                Button ohm2volt = FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.Ohm2VoltButton);
                Button ohm2home = FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.Ohm2HomeButton);

                ohm2amp.Click += delegate
                {
                    SetContentView(Resource.Layout.AmpScreen);
                };

                ohm2volt.Click += delegate
                {
                    SetContentView(Resource.Layout.VoltScreen);
                };

                ohm2home.Click += delegate
                {
                    SetContentView(Resource.Layout.Main);
                };

            };
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your problem is that you are replacing the entire view each time - so the button instances are changing.

What happens inside SetContentView is that the InflatorService gets asked to create a brand new set of UI objects based on the passed in XML, the existing UI is wiped clean and then those new UI objects are put in their place.

It doesn't matter if the new UI objects happen to have the same resource identifiers as the old objects - they are still separate instances.

If you want to continue using your current approach, then you need to rewire all your events after each SetContentView - e.g.

```
        ohm2amp.Click += delegate
            {
                SetContentView(Resource.Layout.AmpScreen);
                RewireEvents();
            };
```

with

```
       private void RewireEvents()
       {
           var ohm2home = FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.ohm2home);
           ohm2home.Click += { /* todo */ };
           // etc
       }
```

alternatively, maybe consider a different UI:

- e.g. you could change the Visibility on different child layouts rather than calling SetContentView to replace everything
- e.g. or you could use multiple activities (or tabs) instead of a single activity

Hope that helps

Comment: Thank you very much Stuart.

I made your suggested changes and implemented a few tentative tests and was pleased at their success.  My entire GUI is now complete in terms of getting the overall structure done.